# Why does my pointer to the first element of a vector get lost?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, stdvector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
//#include <string>

struct Point {
    Point(int _x, int _y) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }

    int x;
    int y;
    Point *parent;
};

int main() {

    Point start(3, 4);
    std::vector<Point> points; 
    points.push_back(start);
    std::cout << points.back().x << "," << points.back().y << "\n";

    Point one(4, 5);
    one.parent = &points.at(0);
    //std::cout <<  "testing: " << one.parent->x << "," << one.parent->y << "\n";
    points.push_back(one);
    std::cout << "One: " << points[1].x << "," << points[1].y << "\n";
    std::cout << "One's parents: " << points[1].parent->x << "," << points[1].parent->y << "\n";

    Point two(10, 3);
    two.parent = &points.back();
    points.push_back(two);
    std::cout << "Two: " << points[2].x << "," << points[2].y << "\n";
    std::cout << "Two's parent: " << points[2].parent->x << "," << points[2].parent->y << "\n";

    Point three(12, 7);
    three.parent = &points[1];
    points.push_back(three);
    std::cout << "Three: " << points[3].x << "," << points[3].y << "\n";
    std::cout << "Three's parents: " << points[3].parent->x << "," << points[3].parent->y << "\n";


    return 1;
}
```

I get the following results:
3,4
One: 4,5
One's parents: **0,0**
Two: 10,3
Two's parent: 4,5
Three: 12,7
Three's parents: 4,5

Even though I made one's parent point to the vector's first element, the value ends up being 0,0. But, the other pointers point to the element that I want it to.

Comment: Once you do `points.push_back(one);` `std::vector` is allowed to reallocate whole array where all the data is kept, so this means if you previously stored pointer such as: `&points.back()`, it might be no longer valid.

Comment: Note: A much safer solution to this problem that would scale if you needed to expand the code would be to make the `vector` a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Point>>`, and have `parent` member of `Point` be a `std::shared_ptr<Point>` as well (assuming it's a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph); if it can have cycles, `std::weak_ptr<Point>` would be needed, and management gets harder). This avoids the tight coupling you've got between the `Point`s and the `vector` that stores them (where `parent` only makes sense in the context of an effectively global `vector`).

Comment: With judicious use of `std::make_shared` (which is both safer and allows performance optimizations that direct `std::shared_ptr` can't do), it wouldn't add too much overhead, and it would free you up quite a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::vector` has a `capacity`. If you add elements beyond the vector's current capacity, vector may decide to allocate a larger block, move the existing elements, and then add the new elements. This must have happened in your case too.

You can bump the capacity of an existing vector with `reserve`. This will not yet add extra elements; it just prepares the vector.

Comment: To be clear: It will potentially consume memory for the raw instance structure for the extra elements (definitely virtual address space, the amount of real RAM occupied is extremely implementation dependent), so for the case of a `std::vector<Point>` in the OP's case, calling `reserve` will typically reserve 12-16 bytes of memory (depending on pointer width) times the size of the reservation. It won't have to initialize the memory, and for classes whose instances store expensive attributes indirectly on the heap, that cost isn't paid immediately, but it must reserve the raw internal array.

Answer (score 0):

While MSalters correctly explained the reason of the issue, and the possible solution for this particular case, the general practice is a bit different. Because `vector` may be reallocated at any moment, it's generally bad idea to store pointers to its elements. 
You may use indices instead, which will be valid regardless of the re-allocation; or you may consider using different data structure, such as `std::list`.
Elements of `std::list` remain in the same location all their lifetime.

Comment: Note: If you *know* the final or maximum size of the `vector`, an appropriate `reserve` call can ensure valid pointers remain valid as long as the element in question isn't moved/replaced. I wouldn't say it's *always* a bad idea to store pointers to `vector` elements, merely that it's a bad idea if you can't `reserve`/`resize` the `vector` once to a size that it never exceeds.

Comment: @ShadowRanger you're right about this. But doing this you got to be 100% sure nobody will want to add more elements in the `vector` in future, say in 5 or 10 years after initial development. When product requirement may evolve to something completely different.

Comment: @Jurlie: Good design would be to encapsulate that vector in a class, with a well-defined external interface. If product requirements evolve, it is then possible to consider if the class can be used as-is, needs to be updated, or a rewrite is needed.